# pyclustering: intended method of initializing kmeans

Tags: python

On wikipedia, there is a description of how to initialize the kmeans cluster locations according to a random method.

In [pyclustering](https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering), a python clustering library, the various clusters are implemented with a high performance c-core.  This core is faster than numpy/sklearn, so I want to avoid implementing anything in sklearn/numpy (or else I might lose the speedy feel of the code right now).

However, the [kmeans class](http://pythonhosted.org/pyclustering/classpyclustering_1_1cluster_1_1kmeans_1_1kmeans.html#details) requires an initial cluster location list to get going.  What is the intended method of initializing these cluster locations in pyclustering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [automatically generated pyclustering documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/pyclustering/) where API of **kmeans** algorithm is described.

For example, you have a 2D-data where two clusters should extracted, then you need to specify initial centers (pyclustering doesn't generate initial centers they should be provided by user):

```
kmeans_instance = kmeans(sample, [ [0.0, 0.1], [2.5, 2.6] ], ccore = True);
```

Where [0.0, 0.1] is a initial center on the first cluster and [2.5, 2.6] is a initial center of the second. Flag 'ccore = True' is for CCORE library usage.

Run processing:

```
kmeans_instance.process();
```

Obtain clustering result:

```
clusters = kmeans_instance.get_clusters(); # list of clusters
centers = kmeans_instance.get_centers(); # list of cluster centers.
```

Visualize obtained result:

```
visualizer = cluster_visualizer();
visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, sample);
visualizer.append_cluster(start_centers, marker = '*', markersize = 20);
visualizer.append_cluster(centers, marker = '*', markersize = 20);
visualizer.show();
```

[Click here to see example of result visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HFJd.png)

Usage examples can be found in: 'pyclustering/cluster/example/kmeans_examples.py'

```
$ ls pyclustering/cluster/examples/ -1
__init__.py
agglomerative_examples.py
birch_examples.py
clarans_examples.py
cure_examples.py
dbscan_examples.py
dbscan_segmentation.py
general_examples.py
hsyncnet_examples.py
kmeans_examples.py  <--- kmeans examples
kmeans_segmentation.py
kmedians_examples.py
kmedoids_examples.py
optics_examples.py
rock_examples.py
somsc_examples.py
syncnet_examples.py
syncsom_examples.py
syncsom_segmentation.py
xmeans_examples.py
```